# Google PIxel 7 suddenly "dead" - no dropped, no water damage, etc

Tags: google-pixel

I have a Google Pixel 7, in good overall condition, working as my daily phone and I was using it just this morning. About an hour later it was totally dead.

To the best of my knowledge, not dropped, no water damage, no sudden shock to it. I plugged the USB calble in from my normal high wattage charger to check the battery isn't dead, but nothing on the screen, no vibration feedback at all.

The phone was in a large metal/rubber protective case as well. I've since removed the case to inspect the phone itself for damage, but everything seems visibly fine. The phone isn't hot, or even warm, etc.

I'm don't want to lose the photos and documents on the internal storage (they're not backed up recently), so I'm worried that a hard reset would loose these.

Do you have any other options you could suggest?

Comment: Okay, almost as suddenly as it stopped working, it's now working again. I did do a soft reset (Power + Volume down for 15 seconds) but it hadn't seemed to do anything. I'm just greatful that it's working again.